# How to export/print "Assembly Dependencies graph" generated by VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, graph, dependencies, export

I created a pretty nice graph of dependencies in my project by VS2012, the file extension is .dgml

I want to export/convert it to GIF / PNG / JPG / PDF etc.
How can I do this without using print-screen (which forces fit the graph to screen size)?
The graph can't be open by the following:
Image viewer, MS-Word, MS-Paint, Photoshop.

Here is part of the graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some research I found it.
It can be done this way:
Edit -> Copy Image, then paste it in other program.

Note, the current resolution is saved, so zoom to the desired resolution before you do the copy.